# Hazelcast distributed queue

Tags: queue, distributed, hazelcast

In Hazelcast documentation, it's said that:

> Hazelcast distributed queue performs no batching while iterating over the queue. All items will be copied locally and iteration will occur locally.
>   http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/queue.html

can some one explain what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that each item is retrieved separately and therefor there is quite a performance hit. A faster approach is to retrieve e.g. 10 items in 1 go to reduce the number of remote calls. Unfortunately this isn't implemented.